# Create multiple aggregates in one transaction

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, transactions, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

My bounded context(inventory) receives an event with quantity 5. Where 5 is the number of pallets were unloaded from the truck in the warehouse. And now in my inventory BC I want to create 5 aggregates (foreach pallet 1 aggregate). How can I do that in my application layer? What if I succeed to create only 3 of them? I can't create them transitionally, cause my persistent storage is file based. What should I do?

Comment: This is a *very* broad question. And it's hard to answer because you don't give any meaningful, if even contradictory, details of your environment. Labeling Entity Framework and using a file-based database doesn't compute. I don't think you use file-base databases designed for unit testing with EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably treat the recording of the receipt event and generation of the five pallets as two separate transactions.

The changes are across two aggregates in your case, but your application service should ideally deal with one single aggregate, as much as possible. **Domain Events** are the right structures to solve such problems of extended transactions, be it between aggregates in a single BC, or across BCs.

So your application service would record the receipt of five pallets as a transaction, and bubble up a domain event (say `PalletsUnloaded`) with sufficient context and data. The event would be passed on as a data structure to a message broker, to be retrieved by subscribers registered for the domain event.

The Pallet aggregate would then catch the event through an event-specific subscriber and process it, in one of two ways:

1. You can create the five pallets in one single pass. Transaction-wise, this approach is a bit risky because if you are using files as persistent storage, there may be failures and you may not have granular data to identify the exact issue
2. You catch the event and create five separate event messages (say `CreatePallet`), each of which is submitted back to the message broker. A subscriber for this event would pick them up and create pallet records one by one. You will accurately know which one failed and why

The 2nd approach is also safer because if you use reliable message brokers like RabbitMQ as the transfer mechanism for events, you can send the errored event into a dead-letter queue or set up mechanisms to retry the processing later. You can also build a separate error-handling process/view that deals with, and processes, errored events.

Answer (score 4):

The usual answer goes something like this -- the first thing that we do is save the *event* in a "TODO" list.

Our "subscription" to this list needs to keep track of, which is to say *write down*, how far it has gotten in the todo list.  For instance, we might treat the TODO list as an append only sequence of events, and the subscription writes down the index of the last completely processed event.

When the subscription runs, it looks up the first unprocessed event in the list, and does the work in how ever many transactions you need.  After all of that work is done, it updates its own counter (another transaction), and can move on.

If the processing *fails*, then we never reach the "write it down" step; so when we restart it will try to process the same event again.

For this to work, we need two properties: one is that running the processor again should produce the *same* list of identifiers for the aggregates, and that the processor knows that the aggregate may have already been created, and acts appropriately in that case.

So in the worst case: we get the event with 5 pallets.  We create all 5 new aggregates, then crash before it can document that the event has been fully processed.  The process restarts, and begins work on the same event.  It discovers that each of the new aggregates has already been created, so each of those steps becomes a no-op.  Finally, having completed all of the processing for the event, it documents that the event has been completed.

In other words, we need idempotent processing.